# Why aren't todo items rendering in desired react component? (asp.net core 2.0/reactjs/typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

Looking for some assistance/guidance of what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to React/Typescript and this is my first demo app. My environment is Visual Studio 2017 Community using asp.net core 2.0, react, and typescript. My starting point is using the react boiler project template.

I am unable to get my todo items from the getTodosApi method to print in the ToDoItem component ToDoItem.tsx); however, when I omit that component and just inline the {item.title} between the LI tags in the render method of the ToDoList component (index.tsx), it prints out just fine. Would appreciate some assistance/guidance with resolving this issue. Thanks in advance!

Here are a couple screen shots:
[Rendering from ToDoList component (Desired Result, but not desired component)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au4K7.png)
[Unable to render todo items in desired ToDoItem component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLX96.png)

I've included below the 2 files I'm working with.

```
//*** index.tsx ***

import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { TodoItem, ITodoItemProps } from './ToDoItem';
import './css/index.css';

const getTodosApi = () => {
    return [
        {
            id: '1',
            title: 'task 1',
            completed: false
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            title: 'task 2',
            completed: false
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            title: 'task 3',
            completed: false
        }
    ];
}

interface ITodoItem {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    completed: boolean
}

interface ITodoListState {
    todos: ITodoItem[];
}

type ITodoListProps = RouteComponentProps<{}>;

export class TodoList extends React.Component<ITodoListProps, ITodoListState> {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            todos: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const todos = getTodosApi();
        this.updateTodoState(todos)
    }

    getTodosFromState = () => this.state.todos ? this.state.todos : []; 

    updateTodoState = (todos: ITodoItemProps[]) => {
        this.setState({
            todos: todos
        })
    }

    handleAddingTodoItem = (todoItem: ITodoItemProps) => {
        let todos = this.getTodosFromState()
        todos.push(todoItem);
        this.updateTodoState(todos);
    }

    handleDeletingTodoItem = (selectedItemToDelete: ITodoItemProps) => {
        const todos = this.getTodosFromState().filter(stateItem => selectedItemToDelete.title !== stateItem.title);
        this.updateTodoState(todos);
    }

    getTodoItemComponents = () => {

        const items = this.getTodosFromState();
        return [...items].map((item: ITodoItemProps) => {
            return (

                //THIS RENDERS EACH TODO ITEM
                //<li>{item.title}</li>

                //THIS DOES NOT RENDER EACH TODO ITEM
                <TodoItem key={item.id} { ...item } />

                //NOR, DOES THIS WORK...
                //<TodoItem
                //    completed={item.completed}
                //    id={item.id}
                //    title={item.title}
                //    key={item.id}
                ///>
            );
        });
    }

    public render () {
        return (
            <div id="todo-list">
                <h2>To Do Items</h2>
                <ul>{ this.getTodoItemComponents() }</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


/**************************************/

//*** ToDoItem.tsx ***

/* HAVE ISSUE WITH GETTING EACH TODO ITEM TO PRINT OUT FROM THIS COMPONENT */

import * as React from 'react';
import './css/todoItem.css';

export interface ITodoItemProps {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    completed: boolean
}

export interface ITodoItemExtProps extends ITodoItemProps {
    key: string;
}

export const TodoItem = (props: ITodoItemExtProps) => {
    return (
        <li>
            <div className="todo-item">
                {props.title}
            </div>
        </li>
    );
};
```

Here's what is loaded in my project (ASP.net core 2.0, React, Typescript):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/react": "15.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it was a caching situation with my IDE. This code works as I had hoped.